# Java time base buffer

Tags: java, java-11

I need a buffer based on time not array of bytes .

I have a stream of data consumed from network socket  ; i need buffer this stream every 5 second .

```
                 +-----------------+
Input Stream --->| 5 second buffer |--> Process data 
                 +-----------------+
```

**Note:** this buffer need to flushed after data processed .
Java 11 has any implementation of this type of buffer ?
i search in google but can not found a solution .

Thank you

Comment: If you know the maximum throughtput of your input stream, create a buffer in memory to store the maximum amount of data that would get through in 5 seconds, and just store the timestamps of every time you flush the buffer empty, dumping it to be processed. You can also have a double buffer (instead of dumping), one that get's filled while you process the other, and you might save a lot of byte copying.

Comment: Are you trying to stream audio/video and ensure that there is at least 5 seconds worth of content available for processing at any given time? Or do you just need a buffer to read for 5 seconds (buffer capacity will vary)?

Comment: no , this stream is not a audio/video , i just need to stream every 5 seconds .